# Angular8/TypeScript: map.set() is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I have the classes `meal` and `mealplan`. A property of mealplan is a map **mealsPerWeek** which contains the weekday as a key and an **object of meal**.

**meal.ts**

```
export class Meal {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  price: number;
}
```

**mealplan.ts**

```
export class Mealplan {
  id: number;
  mealsPerWeek: Map<Weekday, Meal>;

  constructor() {
    this.mealsPerWeek = new Map();
  }
}
```

**weekday.ts**

```
export enum Weekday {
   Monday = 0,
   Tuesday = 1,
   Wednesday = 2,
   Thursday = 3,
   Friday = 4
}
```

Now I want to add meals to the mealsPerWeek map property via PostMapping and a Reactive Form (Angular). The data from the form gets sent to the component:

**mealplan-detail.component.ts**

```
export class MealplanDetailComponent implements OnInit {
 addMealToMealplanForm: FormGroup;
 private meals: Meals[];
 private mealplan: Mealplan;
 private meal: Meal;

 // constructor() { }
 ngOnInit() {
  this.getMeals();
  this.getMealplan();

 .... (form constructor)
 }

 addMealToMealplan(): void {
      this.mealplanService.addMealToMealplan(this.mealplan, this.selectedMeal.value, 
      this.selectedWeekday.value).subscribe(() => {
        this.mealplan.mealsPerWeek.set(this.selectedWeekday.value, 
this.selectedEssen.value);
      });
    }
  }

  get selectedMeal() {
    return this.addMealToMealplanForm.get('meal');
  }

  get selectedWeekday() {
    return this.addMealToMealplanForm.get('weekday');
  }
```

The main problem is, that `this.mealplan.mealsPerWeek.set(this.selectedWeekday.value, this.selectedEssen.value);` is not working. The console prints: `this.mealplan.mealsPerWeek.set is not a function`.

Important is, that the value of `this.selectedWeekday.value` is the ID of the enum, and the value of `this.selectedEssen.value` is an object of meal.

Is the method "set" maybe a wrong method? Do I need to use another method?

**Method in mealplan Service:**

```
  addMealToMealplan(mealplan: Mealplan | number, meal: Meal | number, weekday: number): Observable<Meal> {
    const mealplanId = typeof mealplan === 'number' ? mealplan : mealplan.id;
    const mealId = typeof meal === 'number' ? meal : meal.id;

    const url = `${this.mealplanUrl}/${mealplanId}/add/${mealId}/wt=${weekday}`;
    return this.http.post<Meal>(url, mealId);
  }
```

**addMealToMealPlan Form using Reactive Forms:**

```
 <form [formGroup]="addMealToMealplanForm" 
  <div class="form-group">
    (ngSubmit)="addMealToMealplan()">
         <label for="meal">Meal</label>
        <select id="meal" formControlName="meal">
          <option *ngFor="let meal of meals" [ngValue]="meal" 
    [label]="meal.name"></option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="weekday">Weekday</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="weekday" formControlName="weekday">
      <option *ngFor="let key of weekdayOptions" [value]="key" [label]="weekday[key]"></option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <button class="btn" type="submit">Add Meal to Mealplan</button>
</form>
```

Comment: The service method may be important here. As is how you’re creating your mealPlan object, as I don’t see a constructor that actually creates a map. Declaring types isn’t enough. You need to write the implementation logic

Comment: @bryan60 okay, I added the service method. I dont have any constructors, because I am getting the data from an API.

Comment: But the JSON won't be parsed to a Map, just an object.

Comment: then you need to add a constructor or honestly, just don't use a map

Comment: I added a constructor and it still gives me an error.

Comment: Can you share how you are initializing `this.mealplan`?

Comment: And where do you *use* that constructor? Again, the JSON will be parsed to simple objects. See e.g. all of the questions I linked to https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25401. This is why the docs recommend using an interface not a class.

Comment: To be honest, I dont really understand your point, because in other forms where i add simple objects it works. I dont really understand how I realize the mapping. @AlbertoRivera I edited my opening post. Is this enough?

Comment: I wrote the constructor into the mealplan class. I know, that I am not really calling this constructor anywhere in the code, but I dont know where I should? Because when I am calling the Mealplan from the API I dont know where I should call that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you haven't provided enough info for a definite answer, but you need to actually construct the `MealPlan` object with `new` somewhere in order to use class methods, like those that are on a set, otherwise the constructor doesn't run and you're just lying to TypeScript about the type.  TypeScript doesn't automatically construct objects for you just via casting.

somewhere in your code you need either:

```
 this.mealPlan = new MealPlan();
 // logic to populate properties
```

or if you're getting the initial value from an http call of some kind:

```
getMealPlan() {
  return this.http.get('mealplan.url.com').pipe(
    map(mpResponse => {
      const mp = new MealPlan();
      // logic to populate with response values
      return mp;
    })
  );
}
```

or you can encapsulate that response population logic in your constructor:

```
export class Mealplan {
  id: number;
  mealsPerWeek: Map<Weekday, Meal>;

  constructor(mealPlanResponse) {
    this.id = mealPlanResponse.id;
    this.mealsPerWeek = new Map();
    // logic to populate
  }
}
```

so you can just do

```
 map(mpResponse => new MealPlan(mpResponse))
```

HOWEVER.... you're causing yourself a lot of pain and complexity by using a set, and i'm not sure i see the benefit from the code provided. Just define your meal as an interface and do this:

```
export interface Mealplan {
  id: number;
  mealsPerWeek: {[key in Weekday]: Meal};
}
```

then you don't need to do any constructing ever and you set values easily:

```
this.mealplan.mealsPerWeek[this.selectedWeekday.value] = this.selectedEssen.value;
```

final note, if you want to allow the `mealsPerWeek` object to be partially filled in this interface as it would be allowed in a set (IE only a Monday enum), you'll need to declare it as a Partial:

```
mealsPerWeek: Partial<{[key in Weekday]: Meal}>;
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I think you are right, that I am better off with using an interface instead of a class - I thought that it would be better, because I have done the tour of heroes tutorial - and because in my backend I am using the property as a Map too. But your solution works. Can I ask you one more simple question? For the purpose of the PostRequest, I needed the Weekday Enum as the key(e.g. 0 for monday) Now, with your solution it seems like I would need both, and I would need to convert it. Is there a simple way for this purpose?

Comment: Why do you need both? The keys are the numbers in the interface as they were in the set. As far as I can see, you should not need to change anything else.

Comment: I guess I figured it out. I used: `this.mealplan.mealsPerWeek[Weekday[this.selectedWeekday.value]] = this.selectedMeal.value;`